# Android Studio uninstalling previous app on testing upgrade to my app

Tags: android, android-install-apk, app-update

I have already installed my signed apk app on my device. Now I am giving an update to my app. when I install update from android studio, It asks to uninstall previous app (Obviously because sign identity). I want to import some data from previous app package. So is there anyway to run my current app and debug it over the previous app as an update.

I have searched for this and could not get any similar question. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using gradle? Then you can solve your problem using the "Install Release" Build instead of simply pressing "run" in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes I did the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible, You have to sign the new version using the same debug key